# Choosing a random styled component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have probably an impossible thing I would like to do for my portfolio site. I want to use the React-Burger-Menu library and import all of the menu components and choose one at random upon screen load. I decided to create an array with all of the imports and use a math.random function to see if that will work. Of course, it doesn't. I understand this is probably really dumb, but I think it would be so cool if it worked. Here is what I have so far for the random function:

```
import { slide as Menu0 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { stack as Menu1 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { elastic as Menu2 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { bubble as Menu3 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { push as Menu4 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { pushRotate as Menu5 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { scaleDown as Menu6 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { scaleRotate as Menu7 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { fallDown as Menu8 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { reveal as Menu9 } from 'react-burger-menu';

Menus = Array[Menu0, Menu1, Menu2, Menu3, Menu4, Menu5, Menu6, 
Menu7, Menu8, Menu9]

var Menu = Menus[Math.floor(Math.random() * Menus.length)];

export default Menu;
```

And here like it says in the documentation I am wrapping my nav with `<Menu></Menu>` tags. Here is the code:

```
import Menu from './sidebar';
import Contact from "../pages/contact";
import Portfolio from "../pages/portfolio";
import Index from "../pages/index";
import "../styles/customnav.css";

class customnav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Menu>
        <HashRouter>
          <div>
           <nav className="stroke">
            <ul className="menu">
            <li>
              <NavLink className="menu-item" to="/">
                Home
            </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink className="menu-item" to="/portfolio">
                Portfolio
            </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink className="menu-item" to="/contact">
                Contact
            </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
          <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          </nav>
         </div>
      </HashRouter>
     </Menu>
    );
 }
}
```

export default customnav;

Here is the error code:
`Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

I realize this is a stretch, but thank you for your help.

Comment: Would you post error message as well as the code that imports `Menu`?

Comment: @SungKim I went ahead and changed the OP thank you

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. You don't need `Array` at the beginning of the array of menus. Also use a proper variable declaration with `let/const`. For example, `const Menus = [Menu0, Menu1, ...]`

Comment: @Jayce444 I think this fixed it, Nothing is showing, but it did render so I wonder if I just need to edit my CSS. Thank you very much. I'm too use to ES5

Comment: @Jayce444 do you think there is a good way to test if this works or not? It shows in developer tools that the menu is rendering, but I can't actually see it

Comment: Well you already know that the rendering works. Sounds like a CSS issue, though it's hard to say. I don't have experience with that specific module.

Comment: @Jayce444 Thank you for your help. It does in fact work and I have been messing around with the css. Take care!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong syntax of array, you can just do

```
import { slide as Menu0 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { stack as Menu1 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { elastic as Menu2 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { bubble as Menu3 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { push as Menu4 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { pushRotate as Menu5 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { scaleDown as Menu6 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { scaleRotate as Menu7 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { fallDown as Menu8 } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { reveal as Menu9 } from 'react-burger-menu';

const Menus = [Menu0, Menu1, Menu2, Menu3, Menu4, Menu5, Menu6, 
Menu7, Menu8, Menu9];

const Menu = Menus[Math.floor(Math.random() * Menus.length)];

export default Menu;
```

Comment: Is there any way you can think of to test it?

Comment: @G.Rose Since you used random function, you can't really test your output all depends on your code. However, you can stub the Math.random method to make it always get a certain number, and compare the output with the one you expected.

Answer (score 1):

When using `Array` to create an array, you need to use `Array()`, not `Array[]`

[image]

Demo

```js
console.log(Array[1,2,3]);
console.log(Array(1,2,3));
// OR
console.log([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: Do you think there is a good way to test if this works or not? It shows in developer tools that the menu is rendering, but I can't actually see it